# Adding a custom preprocessing task in Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm migrating my project build toolchain from python/MinGW to msbuild/MSVC.
I need to perform additional preprocessing on some c++ files before each build.
This is performed by my own python script.
Is there a way to do this without writing a extension? 'Custom Build Tool' doesn't allow to modify current source files. Is there any option to "chain" this with build step?

Comment: "'Custom Build Tool' doesn't allow to modify current source files."--Do you mean you can not modify the project file?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I mean project source *.cpp files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adding a custom preprocessing task in Visual C++

Since you do not want to modify the source file, you can use the copy task to back up your scource files to the intermediate directory:

```
<ItemGroup>  
    <MySourceFiles Include="c:\MySourceTree\**\*.cpp"/>  
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyFiles">
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="Destination\Intermediate directory"
    />
</Target>
```

Then use the csc task to compile it before build:

```
<ItemGroup>

  <Compile Include="…\Intermediate directory\filename">

 </Compile>

</ItemGroup>

 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">

    <Message Text="Running your python script on the Intermediate directory folder..."/>

 </Target>
```

See ["Preprocessing" each source file before compilation?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63854a5b-bda6-401b-963c-8121216e45f2/preprocessing-each-source-file-before-compilation?forum=msbuild) for more details.

**Update for comment:**

> Question is all about whether you can call your own target on build
>   failed.

You can use MSBuild command line with specify your custom target to build it:

```
msbuild.exe "YouProjectName.vcxproj" /t:BeforeBuild;Build
```

Then MSBuild will build your custom build first whether your build is failed or successfully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, but it still does not allow to preprocess current files. If I run python script on current file it will be modified and I don't want it

Comment: @kubawal, Got it. You can check my updated answer, check if it helps you.

Comment: That works but if the compilation fails everything stops and backed files are not restored

Comment: Question is all about whether you can call your own target on build failed.

Comment: @kubawal, Yes, you can use MSBuild command line to specify the custom target and build(Custom target before Build.), check the update answer for details.